# How to change user fields programmatically in Osclass?

Tags: php, sql, database, dao, osclass

I need to change user field "b_company" in Osclass. But can't find any information about how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

It was not different solution:

```
          User::newInstance()->updateByPrimaryKey(['b_company' => 1], $user['pk_i_id']);
```